# Build a simple ("static") message extension that just returns a button with a link

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I need to build an extremely simple message extension, that once it's clicked (in a teams channel conversation, the same way the "gif" button is clicked) just shows a card with a text and a button (and then when `enter` is pressed, it's just sent).

I'm a beginner when it comes to message extensions development, I used the instructions from [this Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/first-message-extension?tabs=vscode), and now I'm trying to scrap what I don't need from the generated project and just leave / add what I need.

***What I have until now (relevant parts)***

**in the manifest file**

```
"composeExtensions": [
    {
        "botId": "{botId}",
        "commands": [
            {
                "id": "createCard",
                "context": [
                    "compose"
                ],
                "description": "Command to run action to create a Card from Compose Box",
                "title": "Create Card",
                "type": "action",
                 "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "title",
                        "title": "Card title",
                        "description": "Title for the card",
                        "inputType": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "subTitle",
                        "title": "Subtitle",
                        "description": "Subtitle for the card",
                        "inputType": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "text",
                        "title": "Text",
                        "description": "Text for the card",
                        "inputType": "textarea"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "messageHandlers": [
            {
                "type": "link",
                "value": {
                    "domains": [
                        "*.botframework.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

**in the bot implementation**

```
export class MessageExtensionBot extends TeamsActivityHandler {

  public async handleTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitAction(
    context: TurnContext,
    action: any
  ): Promise<any> {
    switch (action.commandId) {
      case "createCard":
        return createCardCommand(context, action);
      default:
        throw new Error("NotImplemented");
    }
  }
}

async function createCardCommand(context: TurnContext, action: any): Promise<any> {
  const cardJson = {
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
      {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "Click the button below to launch Custom Link"
      }
    ],
    "actions": [
      {
        "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
        "title": "Launch Custom Link",
        "url": "https://google.com"
      }
    ]
  };
  const adaptiveCard = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(cardJson);
  const attachment = {
    contentType: adaptiveCard.contentType,
    content: adaptiveCard.content,
    preview: adaptiveCard,
  };
  return {
    composeExtension: {
      type: "result",
      attachmentLayout: "list",
      attachments: [attachment],
    },
  };
}
```

***What I have working***: when I click the message extension button, I get prompted to enter those  three properties (`title`, `subtitle`, `text`), and **only after that**, I do get my dummy card displayed.

***What I need to do***:

- eliminate that properties prompt completely, I don't need those. **I would only need to directly display the adaptive card, without prompting/waiting any other user action**
- - I tried clearing that section from the manifest, but then the app does not work at all: after redeployment I **still** get prompted for the properties and I get an error no matter if/what I enter

**How can I achieve that ?**

- **what do I need to remove/add to the manifest ?**
- **what method do I need to implement in the bot class ?**

Can anybody help somehow ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to make something like GIF messaging extension in Teams then you should try template - [Custom Stickers App Template (C#)](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-stickers#custom-stickers-app-template). If you refer this template you will also get [manifest](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-stickers/blob/master/manifest/manifest.json), which you just need to configure with your bot Id.

**Explanation of manifest** -

The part that you need in manifest is only simple [composeExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#composeextensions) with command type `query`

```
"composeExtensions": [
        {
            "botId": "<bot id>",
            "canUpdateConfiguration": false,
            "commands": [
                {
                    "id": "Search",
                    "type": "query",
                    "title": "Search",
                    "description": "",
                    "initialRun": true,
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "name": "keyword",
                            "title": "keyword",
                            "description": "search for a sticker"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

As I understand from the question you asked, you want something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSJ8y.png

**In the bot handler** -

You need to implement `handleTeamsMessagingExtensionQuery(context, query)`. Here you can use argument `query` to search for the image you want to send. If you want to see how to implement, we have a sample ready for it(not in context of GIF but you will get general idea)- [*Sample link*](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/50.teams-messaging-extensions-search/bots/teamsMessagingExtensionsSearchBot.js).

In this method you need to return messaging extension response. In it you will return all the results(attachment).

Attachment is consist of `preview` and `content`. Preview get renders in the messaging extension. Once you click on the preview, its `content` get render in compose box.
Refer this on how to return messaging extension response having `preview` as [`thumbnail card`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#thumbnail-card) and `content` as [`adaptive card`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#adaptive-card) - [*link*](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/9d5676e7c36be4137676b131722f6b6cb7469669/samples/javascript_nodejs/50.teams-messaging-extensions-search/bots/teamsMessagingExtensionsSearchBot.js#L52-L69)

You can use this Adaptive card JSON as you just want to show image in it

```
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.0",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "Image",
      "url": "https://adaptivecards.io/content/cats/1.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

- Refer [*this*](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Image.html) for more image related samples.